# Automatically Styling Text in CKEditor5 as you type

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am fairly new to using CKEditor5 and I am struggling a bit to understand the upcasting/downcasting process.

I would like to create a plugin that, on typing, automatically finds and styles text based on the content, without changing the data that would be output. I assume I want to only affect the view, but everything I try seems to have adverse effects.

Assuming we want to highlight the word "world" in "Hello World", the view should appear like, so, while the getData would just return "Hello World".

```
<p>Hello <u>World</u></p>
```

I'm not exactly sure how to set up the plugin so that it is always active on the editor content and updating the view.

Has anyone had any success with automatically styling text as the user types? Any pointers or further reading would be greatly appreciated, thanks!